# Is anything known about the credits artwork from The Seventh Voyage of Sinbad?

Tags: art, seventh-voyage-of-sinbad

The opening credits of *The Seventh Voyage of Sinbad* (a Harryhausen monster classic) features the camera panning across an artwork that shows scenes from the film.

It looks like a rather interesting mixed media (painting and other methods) artwork, but there seems to be no indication in the film's credits who made.  Nor can I find any information about what happened to it—whether it was preserved somewhere or ultimately scrapped.  Is there any source with more information about this piece?